# Javascript file not found inside spring project

Tags: java, javascript, spring, jsp

In my jsp page, I have this section in the final of the file where I include the JS files I need:

```
<script src="../resources/jquery/js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="../resources/jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="../resources/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../resources/extras/js/docs.min.js"></script>

<script src="../resources/extras/js/jquery.md5.min.js"></script>
<script src="../resources/extras/js/form_submit.js"></script>
<script src="../resources/extras/js/form_valida.js"></script>
<script src="../resources/extras/js/page_link.js"></script>
<script src="../resources/extras/js/page_load.js"></script>
```

All this files are placed in the folder /WEB-INF/view/jsp/resources from my project:

[image]

But the files docs.min.js and form_valida.js aren't found when I run the project and open the page in the browser.

this is the output in the browser console:

```
Um formulário foi enviado com a codificação windows-1252. Ela não possui todos os caracteres Unicode, portanto os dados do usuário podem ter sido corrompidos. Para evitar este problema, a página deve ser modificada para que o formulário seja enviado com a codificação UTF-8. Isso pode ser feito modificando a codificação da própria página para UTF-8 ou especificando accept-charset=utf-8 no elemento form. login
POST http://localhost:8080/loja/login [HTTP/1.1 302 Found 44 ms]
GET http://localhost:8080/loja/privado/dashboard [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 42 ms]
GET http://localhost:8080/loja/resources/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 15 ms]
GET http://localhost:8080/loja/resources/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 7 ms]
GET http://localhost:8080/loja/resources/jquery/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 7 ms]
GET http://localhost:8080/loja/resources/extras/css/dashboard.css [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 14 ms]
GET http://localhost:8080/loja/resources/extras/css/table.css [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 15 ms]
GET http://localhost:8080/loja/resources/jquery/js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 35 ms]
GET http://localhost:8080/loja/resources/jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 19 ms]
GET http://localhost:8080/loja/resources/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 41 ms]
GET http://localhost:8080/loja/resources/extras/js/docs.min.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 23 ms]
GET http://localhost:8080/loja/resources/extras/js/jquery.md5.min.js [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 28 ms]
GET http://localhost:8080/loja/resources/extras/js/form_submit.js [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 36 ms]
GET http://localhost:8080/loja/resources/extras/js/form_valida.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 24 ms]
GET http://localhost:8080/loja/resources/extras/js/page_link.js [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 29 ms]
GET http://localhost:8080/loja/resources/extras/js/page_load.js [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 40 ms]
GET http://localhost:8080/loja/resources/extras/js/docs.min.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 4 ms]
GET http://localhost:8080/loja/resources/extras/js/form_valida.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 3 ms]
```

Anyone knows what can be happening here?

Comment: Try to clean your project and re-deploy it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script src="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/resources/extras/js/form_valida.js" > </script>
<script src="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/resources/extras/js/docs.min.js" > </script>
```

try this out by giving full path may be it work

Answer (score 0):

/WEB-INF/view/jsp/{FOLDER THAT YOU RUN THE PROJECT IN IT}/{YOUR FILE THAT YOU INCLUDE INTO IT YOUR JS FILES} if you run project in another folder that placed on upper folder it can not run